# How to script git commands in a Windows bat script?

Tags: batch-file, github, git

I want to create a bat script that do the following :

- **opens git bash**
- **run commands on git bash (ex. `git init`, `git add .`, ...)**

Context: I am working on an idea, that I will access git-bash through java.
I use Netbeans IDE

Comment: @TonyHensler I used processBuilder to open the git bas, but cannot write commands on gitBash

Comment: I found an answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401229/how-do-i-execute-several-git-commands-in-a-batch-file-without-terminating-after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401229/how-do-i-execute-several-git-commands-in-a-batch-file-without-terminating-after) Thanks all!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to [open git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17302977/6309) at all to execute a sequence of git commands in a script:

Create your bash script as any other script:

```
#!/bin/bash
git ...
#other commands
```

Save it as `git-myscript` (no extension) anywhere referenced by your `$PATH` or `%PATH%` (this works even on Windows)

Run it with `git myscript`: it will be executed by the git bash.

This work for any file named `git-xxx`: you can call that file as a bash script with `git xxx`.
(on Linux, Mac or Windows)

Comment: Thanks, but i am new to this so can you provide a one line example of this  ? like how to do it for git commit or git add . ?

Comment: @elmaystro Sure: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8482843/6309: make sure to save that script as `git-xxx`, for instance `git-addc`, and you can call it with `git addc`.