# how can i make git log show tree with all my parameters by default?

Tags: git, github

Often I use "**git log --graph --all --decorate --online**" command.

It's verbose and tedious to write it with all the parameters. **I know** that i want these options **always** be applied to my git log cmd.

edit:i want only git to change its behavior - not writing some script outside of it, tweaking win shell or smth!
I want to write **"git log"** and it does

**"git log --graph --all --decorate --online"** automatically

Like in vim, there is probably some default config file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to script git commands in a Windows bat script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660025/how-to-script-git-commands-in-a-windows-bat-script)

Comment: Write a batch script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create aliases in `~/.gitconfig` file.

Basically, add the following to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
     llog = log --graph --all --decorate --online
```

Now when you call `git llog`, it will execute `git log --graph --all --decorate --online`

For furhter information read [this](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases).

Comment: so "git log" is bound forever to just one default behavior? i can't change it? but i can create alias?

Comment: I am not sure about that. But even if it is possible, I think using alias is safer

Comment: great works fine , my productivity will probably go up by 10% now ..))))

Comment: git config --global alias.llog "log --all --graph --decorate --oneline" is the cmd u need to punch in cmd line