# Adding list of files and committing them at same time with a git global alias

Tags: git

Is it possible to do this:

`git add file1 file2 file3 && git commit -m 'blah blah blah'`

with something like this:

`git ac file1 file2 file3 -m 'blah blah blah'`

I'm sure it can be done with a bash script but wondering if git could be jiggered to create a global alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with plain old `git commit`

```
git commit -m "here's the comment" file1 file2 file3
```

By the way, this is not the best thing you can do. The staging area is a pretty powerful tool.... but the fact is that commit can be used this way.

Comment: If you use `-a` then there's no point in listing the files you want to add/commit. -a means "all".

Comment: Ah, perfect. It was driving me crazy to be adding files that were already added to the repo. Never made any sense to me. Now it does: You only have to use the add command for new file. Duh! Thanks!

Comment: Not only _new_ files.... but modified files.... the thing is that you can modify 30 files.... and have them laying around.... then you say "ok.... I only need to commit these 5 files"... those 5 files, you add them to the staging area.... and then you say "oh.... I forgot about this other file".... and you add it to staging area.... then you realize that one of the first 5 files is not to be committed, so you reset it... and so on until you say: ok, ready: `git commit -m "here's the comment"`. What you have on the index will be committed, the other files will not be included in the revision.

Comment: Good point. I don't have disciplined approach for using git yet so I'm kind of all over the map. But I just came off a project making lots of one off, unrelated changes to one file at a time and I kept doing `git add` for each separate file when I could have just committed directly. Was driving me nuts.

Comment: Though I think I'm going to do a bash script so I can do gc 'my changes' file1 file2 file3. Typing -m gets annoying, too.

Comment: Something like this is even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482843/git-commit-bash-script